# conversion Time_Series to data.frame

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following structure:

```
  'data.frame': 240 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Date  : Date, format: "1998-01-01" "1998-02-01" "1998-03-01" ...
 $ rollDE: Time-Series  from 1 to 240: 0.00289 0.00992 -0.00424 0.07958 -0.035 ...
 $ DE$DE : num  0.00289 0.00992 -0.00424 0.07958 -0.035 ...
```

I have implemented the following code for a ggplot of a multiple columns in one plot.

```
> ggplot() + 
+   geom_line(data = yy, aes(x= Date, y = x$`rollDE`, color = "rollingmeanDE")) +
+   geom_line(data = yy, aes(x = Date, y = x$`DE$DE`, color = "DEreturn")) +
+   xlab('Date') + ylab('percent.change')
```

However, error as follows.

```
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type ts. Defaulting to continuous.
```

I have done attempts to convert `$rollDE` but failed. Please any comment to convert it or any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to zoo using `read.zoo` and use `autoplot.zoo`.  Omit `facet = NULL` to get separate panes for the two data columns.  Using `yy` in the Note at the end:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)

autoplot(read.zoo(yy), facet = NULL) + xlab("Date") + ylab("percentage change")
```

[image: screenshot]

### Note

Here is a reproducible version of `yy`. The last column has been doubled so that it does not have identical values to the column before it.

```
yy <- data.frame(
  Date = as.Date(c("1998-01-01", "1998-02-01", "1998-03-01")),
  rollDE = ts(c(0.00289, 0.00992, -0.00424)),
  "DE$DE" = 2*c(0.00289, 0.00992, -0.00424))
```

Comment: Why 2*c(....) at the last row? and No ways to fix it in the ggplot package?

Comment: This is already explained in the Note. `autoplot` is in ggplot2.